# Application to parse profiling output

Tags: .net, profiling, profiler

I'm profiling a .NET application and all I have is a CSV output similar to this:

```
name                calls  inclusive_time  exclusive_time
=========================================================
main                    1        88375485        88363071
len                  1057           14060           14060
join                   60            1635            1635
exists                573          447360          433872
find_vertical_lines   150          279889          138107
clean_text            162          119721          104242
```

Do you know any application which can take profiling information from a file and display some typical profiler stats? I can format the information in different ways if required.

I know that I won't be able to do some operations like drill down the caller tree.

Comment: Sounds like a gprof-style profiler. With or without such a viewer, you're going to run into [these issues.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [PerfConsole](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=5A04EE30-6259-4FAD-BF05-CCB72BE09B4A&displaylang=en).  It was designed as a lightweight, command-line oriented tool for analyzing Visual Studio Profiler reports (.vsp), but you can plug into its data model to benefit from its filtering and analysis.

The download comes with documentation that describes its data model as well as how to actually use the tool.